# Live Script with animation

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

MATLAB 2016a introduced [Live Scripts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/live-scripts.html), allowing to show plotting output next to the script. Is it somehow possible to show animations? For example, the following code in a regular script will plot a few points and then rotate the `axes`:

```
x = rand(10, 3);
plot3(x(:, 1), x(:, 2), x(:, 3), 'o')
for ii = 1:360
    camorbit(1, 10*cos(ii/90*pi)*pi/45)
    drawnow
    pause(0.01)
end
```

If this is embedded in a Live Script, the initial plot is shown, then seemingly nothing happens while the loop is running, then the last aspect (which is the same as the original plot) is shown in a new display item.

Alternatively, is there an option to interact with the plots in a live script (other than double-clicking to open the plot in a new figure)? E.g. `rotate3d` does not have an effect.

**Edit:** As of release 2019a, animations are possible as per [release notes](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html).

Comment: I don't have matlab 2016 to try this, but you could try a few things: 1) in the old publisher you had to use `snapnow` instead of `drawnow` if you wanted a snapshot in the publisher. If Live Scripts have borrowed code from publisher then this might be worth a try. 2) If instead of a for-loop you create an actual movie object and play it back with the `movie` command, the LiveScript might be set up to interpret it correctly. 3) If the LiveScript is proper html-based then it may support animated gifs; create one using `imwrite` and individual frames. (Let me know if any of the above work. :) )

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou thanks for your comments... 1) doesn't work, 2) `movie` only shows last frame, 3) Haven't tried animated gifs. That's last resort :)

Comment: I have the feeling this will have to wait till 2016b..

Comment: Live scripts do not allow to interact with the plots. I can think of a solution to embed a .gif into an .html exported live script. If that could be of any help I can provide a solution, but would recommend submitting a feature request to the mathworks.

Comment: On a marginally related note, [introduced in R2016b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-live-scripts.html#bva1wsm) is zoom/pan/rotation for live editor figure outputs. It's not yet programmatic (at least overtly), but it's moving in a useful direction.

Comment: @excaza ah, it's out.. I wanted to put that into an answer once released ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code as posted in the question produces a rotating plot as of MATLAB 2019a. It does not work yet in 2018b. The [release notes](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) for 2019a mention that

> You can enable for-loop animations in the Live Editor to show changes
>   in plotted data over time. To enable animations in the Live Editor,
>   set the `matlab.editor.AllowFigureAnimations` setting to `true`:
>
> ```
> s = settings;
> s.matlab.editor.AllowFigureAnimation.PersonalValue = true;
> ```

Running these two lines before the example script will yield the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the answer is no - Live Scripts are too young to be that feature rich yet. The fact alone that they're undebuggable would make me stay away from them for 1-2 versions more.
Have you looked into [Matlab Notebooks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-matlab-notebook-with-microsoft-word.html)?   If you're after pretty formatting and some basic interactivity, It might be what you seek.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Notebooks are Windows only?

Comment: MS-word only. What OS are you targeting?

Comment: Just checked, it's [Windows only](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-matlab-notebook-with-microsoft-word.html). I'd like this to work on Windows and Mac, and preferably Linux, too.

Comment: Ok, sorry I can't offer a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Release 2016b added the option to manipulate `axes` with controls that come into view when hovering over the `axes`. Note that this does not work for `axes` that are invisible (`Visible='off'`). Instead, the rulers and background have to be hidden:

```
ax = axes;
x = rand(9, 3);
plot3(ax,x(:, 1), x(:, 2), x(:, 3), 'x'); 
% Hide rulers and background color
ax.Color = [1 1 1 0]; 
ax.XAxis.Visible ='off'; 
ax.YAxis.Visible ='off'; 
ax.ZAxis.Visible ='off';
```

Axes arranged with `subplot` can be manipulated individually as well.